# Is there any way to send an arraylist of int elements from javascritp to spring contoller without using Json?

Tags: javascript

I have a `list`  of `int` elements inside a javaScript code, so I want to send this `list` to a `spring controller`

Comment: If you want to avoid json you can create any format you want and then send it to the server. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: Sure, the body content of a request does not have to be json.  You can make it any contrived pattern that you desire.  In that aspect, this question is slightly broad.

Answer (score 0):

> The API will generally simply return raw data back to the client – XML and JSON representations usually – and so the DispatcherServlet bypasses the view resolvers and returns the data right in the HTTP response body.

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers

**Basically**, what this is saying is you can use XML (which is somewhat common), but I believe other datatypes are possible, as long as you account for them on both sides.

Just use:

```
myMethod(@RequestParam("value1") List<Integer> valueOne)
```

in your Java and send it however you want in your JavaScript (as long is it's documented in Spring)

And you can cast that into whatever. But as far as I know you it's advised to pass it as either XML or JSON.

Comment: Firstly, this solution doesn't even compile (`ArrayList<int>` wouldn't be accepted. `ArrayList<Integer>` would.) and secondly, code to interfaces, not to implementations. Should at the least be `List<Integer>`.

Comment: You're right, I was just looking in the docs and wanted to answer rapidly. My apologies. Changes have been made.